# CSS undetected?

Tags: css, node.js, pug

I was told the reason that I'm not getting this:
[image]

and getting this instead: 
[image]

is because no styles are supplied. So I checked my CSS links:

```
link(href="css/bootstrap.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css")
link(href="elyes.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="jstree/dist/themes/default/style.min.css")
link(href="jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css")
link(href="./Icons/splashy.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css")
link(href="toastr/toastr.css", rel="stylesheet")
link(href="upload-engine/assets/css/styleUploader.css", rel="stylesheet")
link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700", rel="stylesheet")
```

Could somebody tell me according to these links above, where is the css files (css/bootstrap.css, elyes.css, ...)are located? Just to make sure that I'm putting the right paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely using Express.js so you probably have a line that looks like this:
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

This `public` folder is where you need to put your css files.

Basically how this works:
1. The `/account/css/bootstrap.css` request comes in.
2. Express goes through each route to see who wants to handle it.
3. When it gets to the static file serving route (see line above) it doesn't find your CSS file because you put them in a different folder than it's looking it.
4. It then proceeds on to the next route and eventually finds that no route wants to handle it and so you output a 404 error.

Moral of story:
Keep jade views in the `views` folder. These are served when you tell Express to render the jade file.
Keep static files (.css, .js, .html, etc) in the `public` folder. These files get returned when they match the request.

In your case you will want to put the bootstrap css file here:
`public/account/css/bootstrap.css`